# How can Monitor Linux zimbra mail traffic ( in and cout )?

Tags: email-server, spam, email, zimbra

I configured zimbra mail server in linux. Is there any way to monitor e-mail traffic through linux server. Or any way to monitor spam activities on this zimbra mail server.

Thanks for the great help.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor a great deal through the zimbra admin console - https://[your domain here]:7071/zimbraAdmin/.  From the monitoring panel there you can view graphs for email traffic and spam activity.  You are also able to view and export various metrics through the advanced tab.

For more detailed reports of email in and out, you can view the admin report which is automatically mailed to the admin account you set up with the server.

Comment: Thanks for the help. But my intention is monitor spam activity in the linux / zimbra running server. Through that i try to monitor unwanted generation of mails from the local mail server. Any way to monitor this like activities ?